# The probabilistic interpretation of ramanujan's constant $ e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$

Tags: probability, constants

Some of the mathematical constants have interesting probabilistic interpretations. For example,

1. "$\pi$". Suppose two integers are chosen at random. What is the probability that they are comprime, that is, have no common factor exceeding 1? The answer is $\large\frac{6}{\large\pi^2}$
2. "Apery's constant". Given three random integers, the probability that no factor exceeding 1 divides them all is $\large\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}$

Does there exist probabilistic interpretation of Ramanujan's constant $\large e^{\large\pi\large\sqrt{163}}$ ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything even for [Gelfond's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant) $e^\pi$, nor in its [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A039661), so its is doubtful it will be easy to find any probabilistic interpretation for $e^{\pi\sqrt{d}}$.